# Enum doesn't initialize the correct value

Tags: java, enums

I am currently using the enum below.

```
public enum ConditionCode  {
    EQ, SEQ, NE, SNE, CS, SCS, HS, SHS, CC, SCC, LO, SLO, MI, SMI, PL, SPL, VS, SVS, VC, 
    SVC, HI, SHI, LS, SLS,GE, SGE, LT, SLT, GT, SGT, LE, SLE, SAL, AL
}
```

I want to get the enum `ConditionCode.ALS` and print it and compare it to AL by doing this

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    ConditionCode sal = ConditionCode.SAL;
    System.out.print(sal.toString + " ");
    System.out.println(sal.compareTo(ConditionCode.AL) == 0);
}
```

What I find weird is that this command prints `AL` and not `SAL false` and it  the same for all the other enums for example

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    ConditionCode cc = ConditionCode.CC;
    System.out.print(cc.toString + " ");
    System.out.println(cc.compareTo(ConditionCode.AL) == 0);
}
```

will also print `AL` and not `CC false`. Can I know why it does this? And, how can I fix it?

Comment: Your code cannot compile. It will fail at `sal.toString` (parens as missing).

Comment: it will because it will use the java.Lang.Enum.toString(), if you have to change the output of the enum, for example if you want all the enum in you class to print `S` you have to override the function toString with something like `public String toString(){ return 'S'; }` otherwise the default toString is `public String toString(){ return super.toString(); }`

Comment: Voted to close as typo, see OP’s comment on Peter Lawrey’s answer.

Answer (score 2):

This program http://ideone.com/uXiIj8 prints as expected

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    {
        ConditionCode sal = ConditionCode.SAL;
        System.out.print(sal + " ");
        System.out.println(sal.compareTo(ConditionCode.AL) == 0);
    }
    {
        ConditionCode sal = ConditionCode.CC;
        System.out.print(sal + " ");
        System.out.println(sal.compareTo(ConditionCode.AL) == 0);
    }
}

public enum ConditionCode  {
   EQ, SEQ, NE, SNE, CS, SCS, HS, SHS, CC, SCC, LO, SLO, MI, SMI, PL, SPL, VS, SVS, VC, 
    SVC, HI, SHI, LS, SLS,GE, SGE, LT, SLT, GT, SGT, LE, SLE, SAL, AL
}
```

prints

```
SAL false
CC false
```

> Can I know why it does this? And, how can I fix it?

Most likely you are changing the code and re-compiling the program before running it or you are running a different program to the one you think you are.  I would make sure your IDE is set up correctly to re-compile your program before running it and possibly restarting it if it appears fine.

Comment: Thank you for you answer but I found where the problem was in my code, I just didn't pass the correct argument in my function